# Can I make more efficient code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Node ' + (i + 1)));
    document.getElementById('nodeHolder').appendChild(el);
}
```

The Javascript code is like this using pure syntax, is anyone make a more efficient logic please?

Comment: This belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why i += 1 ? I'd say i++

Comment: Or shift the start and end point of `i` by 1. Move `getElementById` outside of the loop, only need to get it's reference once. Build the elements in a [`fragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment), then update the DOM when the loop is finished.

Answer (score 4):

you're triggering a browser reflow on every iteration, which decreases heavily the performance , you should instead do:

```
var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment(); // creates empty fragment
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; ++i) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = 'Node ' + i;
    docFragment.appendChild(el);
}
document.getElementById('nodeHolder').appendChild(docFragment);
```

this way you're modifying the dom only once.
 Try to measure the execution time and you'll see a huge difference.
Here's an interesting [article](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom) about optimizing Javascript Dom manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You should get nodeHolder only one time, document.getElementById in every loop is unnecessary

```
var nodeHolder = document.getElementById('nodeHolder')
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML = 'Node ' + (i + 1);
    nodeHolder.appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Edited to add divs.

Its generally quicker to build a string, and then append it to your document in one go. That way you are only touching the DOM once.

```
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    html += "<div>Node " + (i + 1) + "</div>";
}
document.getElementById('nodeHolder').innerHTML = html;
```

Updated Fiddle Here : http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/cGAhq/

*EDIT2:*

As per comments I did some performance testing on the fragment answer vs this answer.

The fragment answer was substantially faster in Firefox and Chrome. The string answer here was slightly faster in Internet Explorer (10). I only tested from one machine, it may be different for older slower machines and different browser versions.

Performance test here:
http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/596cq/1/

Comment: But then there are no `<div>`s for every line of text

Comment: No need to build it as a string, just create all the nodes in a fragment, then update the DOM.

Comment: Xotic: I don't disagree, but would poking data into a fragment actually be faster? Logically, not touching any DOM related functions until the end (outside the loop) is going to be quite efficient. The OP's goal seems to be performance. ooh and I'd certainly add html=""; as an extra line to kill that memory.

Comment: I very much doubt it is slower, you could create a test on [`jsPerf`](http://jsperf.com/) and let us know, at present you only seem to be guessing without any real evidence.

Comment: Turns out you are right, the fragment method is quicker. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/paull3876/596cq/1/ . I swapped the loop with method-- vs method ++ in case of memory caching etc and in both cases the fragment method is faster :) hey its good I learned something ;)

Comment: I just tested it in IE and IE does the string method slightly faster, whereas firefox does the fragment method faster. Chrome also does the fragment method faster.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding your results to your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get every single piece of performance out of your code, you should only use `document.getElementById` once and modify the document once. Also, `Node.prototype.cloneNode` seems to be a bit faster than `Document.prototype.createElement`.

```
var nodeHolder = document.getElementById("nodeHolder"),
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(), // Create a fragment to avoid repetitive manipulation of the document
    templateNode = document.createElement("div"), // Create a template div
    el,
    i;

for (i = 1; i < 1001; i += 1) {
    // Clone the node instead of using createElement
    el = templateNode.cloneNode();
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Node " + i));
    // Append to the fragment
    fragment.appendChild(el);
}

// Append the fragment to the holder
nodeHolder.appendChild(fragment);
```

If I missed something, feel free to tell me.

#### Edits:

"Shift the start and end value of `i` by 1 to eliminate the `(i + 1)`" – Xotic750

Comment: Shift the start and end value of `i` by 1 to eliminate the `(i + 1)`

Comment: @Xotic750 I can't imagine this will make a huge difference, but why not? Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Do you have any performance data for `cloneNode` vs `createElement`, would be interesting to see?

Comment: That seems to show `createElement` to be generally faster.

Comment: @Xotic750 It seems to depend on the browser, its version and how much the node is modified. I think I'll do some more testing to see when it is better to use which.

Comment: Maybe this is a better comparison, by taking the create outside the test loop. http://jsperf.com/22168087 Now `cloneNode` has the edge

Answer (score 0):

You can clone an original div with its text node, so the text can be updated with a digit instead of being created and appended each iteration.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Small Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spawning divs</h1>
<script>

var el, i=0,
pa=document.createDocumentFragment(),     
div= document.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Node '));


while(i<1000){
    var el = div.cloneNode(true);
    el.firstChild.data+=' '+(++i);
    pa.appendChild(el);
}
document.body.appendChild(pa);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```